# Perform array treatment with reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I have an array that i need to treat to extract and form a new object, this is the code i run right now:

```
data_proces = Object.values(selectedData.reduce((r, { Code, Description, Price}) => {    
    r[Description] ??= { Code, Description, Units: 0, Price: 0 , Total: 0};
    r[Description].Code= Code;
    r[Description].Units++;
    r[Description].Price = Price ;
    r[Description].Total += Price ;
    return r;
}, {}));
```

This gives me:

```
[{
    "Code": 0,
    "Description": "No Factured Act",
    "Units": 2,
    "Price": 0,
    "Total": 0
},
{
    "Code": 1,
    "Description": "Autopsy",
    "Units": 1,
    "Price": 44,
    "Total": 44
},
{
    "Code": 2,
    "Description": "Simple Biopsy",
    "Units": 3,
    "Price": 29,
    "Total": 87
},
{
    "Code": 1,
    "Description": "Citology",
    "Units": 4,
    "Price": 15,
    "Total": 60
},
{
    "Code": " -",
    "Description": "Free Act",
    "Units": 2,
    "Price": 56789,
    "Total": 91356
}]
```

And this is the result i want:

```
[{
    "Code": 0,
    "Description": "No Factured Act",
    "Units": 2,
    "Price": 0,
    "Total": 0
},

    "Code": 0,
    "Description": "No Factured Act",
    "Units": 1,
    "Price": 0,
    "Total": 0
},
{
    "Code": 1,
    "Description": "Autopsy",
    "Units": 1,
    "Price": 44,
    "Total": 44
},
{
    "Code": 2,
    "Description": "Simple Biopsy",
    "Units": 3,
    "Price": 29,
    "Total": 87
},
{
    "Code": 1,
    "Description": "Citology",
    "Units": 4,
    "Price": 15,
    "Total": 60
},
{
    "Code": " -",
    "Description": "Free Act",
    "Units": 1,
    "Price": 34567,
    "Total": 34567
},
{
    "Code": " -",
    "Description": "Free Act",
    "Units": 1,
    "Price": 56789,
    "Total": 56789
}]
```

As you can see, i need "No Factured Act" and "Free Act" to NOT sum up their units and stay as an individual values, how can i achieve this with Reduce?.

Comment: Please provide an input array as example.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a Record object, or else you won't be able to have mutliple times the same description... Use an array and push or update values.

Comment: what you are doing groups by description so finally you get an element with some description only once

Comment: just create a unique key for those two descriptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create an array of `Description` properties that you don't want summed and create unique keys if the iterated description is included in the array. Here using the third `index` parameter of the `reduce()` callback.

```js
const selectedData = [{ "Code": 0, "Description": "No Factured Act", "Price": 0, }, { "Code": 0, "Description": "No Factured Act", "Price": 0, }, { "Code": 1, "Description": "Autopsy", "Price": 44, }, { "Code": 2, "Description": "Simple Biopsy", "Price": 29, }, { "Code": 2, "Description": "Simple Biopsy", "Price": 29, }, { "Code": 2, "Description": "Simple Biopsy", "Price": 29, }, { "Code": 1, "Description": "Citology", "Price": 15, }, { "Code": 1, "Description": "Citology", "Price": 15, }, { "Code": 1, "Description": "Citology", "Price": 15, }, { "Code": 1, "Description": "Citology", "Price": 15, }, { "Code": " -", "Description": "Free Act", "Price": 34567, }, { "Code": " -", "Description": "Free Act", "Price": 56789, }];

const noSum = ['No Factured Act', 'Free Act'];

const data_process = Object.values(
  selectedData.reduce((r, { Code, Description, Price }, i) => {

    let key = Description;
    if (noSum.includes(key)) {
      key = `${key}_${i}`;
    }

    r[key] ??= { Code, Description, Units: 0, Price, Total: 0 };
    r[key].Units++;
    r[key].Total += Price;

    return r;
  }, {})
);

console.log(data_process);
```

Comment: Really well explained!!! Thank You!!!!